# Session variables after logout and login

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Some answers are close but not quite the issue I am having. Here is the steps I am taking to cause the problem:

1. Login to our site.  --  Session variables are set.
2. Redirect to default page happens fine.  --  Session variables are correct as the data is displayed correctly.
3. Logout of site.  --  Redirected to login page correctly.
4. Login again.  --  Session variables are set again.
5. Redirect to default page happens.  --  The session variables are null.  The data is not displayed correctly.

Here is how I put the variable into Session during the login.

```
Session.Add("company", companyPrikey);
```

Here is how I reference Session in the default page

```
if (Session["company"] != null)
```

Even though I see `Session.Add` running during the second login, the default page if finding `Session["company"]` to be `null` when it is running `Page_Load()`.

I've looked at `Session.SessionID` and they are the same during each login.

Anything that gets the user away from the site (navigate to different URL, close the tab, close IE) fixes the issue and they can log in correctly again.

**--EDIT--**

The redirect is just in the URL

```
Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=~/History.aspx
```

The login completes and then goes back to the history page.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code around the redirect, to help us hunt for your issue.

Comment: How do you log in and out ? What is the code including the conditions ?

Comment: It is just the default login.aspx that is included by default with a new project.  It has been updated to use active directory.  I added to the button click event to pull the information needed and store it in Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the session may not have been deleted correctly on logout. The null check is therefore failing, and the variables are not being given new values on the subsequent login.

Try `Session.Abandon()` on logout if you aren't already. This will close down the Session *when the page finishes processing*, i.e. don't redirect to a login page straight after the Abandon code.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: It is getting closer.  I tried putting Session.Abandon() in LoggingOut() and in LoggedOut().  When the log in code is executed now, the session variables are not set but it is still not holding the new values.  I am using the asp:LoginView object if that helps any.  One of its properties is LogoutAction.  If I set this to nothing so it doesn't redirect as you stated, how do I get back to the log in page?  Thanks

Comment: Alright, the last piece was to set the LogoutAction to Refresh.  This caused the page to just refresh which then caused a redirect instead of an immediate redirect.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user1552208 - no problem. Glad you've got it all sorted now.